# @GetMapping is not getting imported

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller

[Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKwaG.png)
I am new to Spring MVC and I am doing this project on maven. I was trying to import @GetMapping but it did not get imported. What could be the issue? Could someone please help me?

```
<!-- Spring dependencies --!>
        <!-- Spring IOC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: That should work fine. However, if you're new to Spring, you should start by using a generated project from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io), which will set up all your dependencies with appropriate versions, etc., and let you learn about writing your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to describe `import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;`, [like this](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/blob/master/en62094894/src/main/java/com/example/en62094894/MyController.java#L4).

Eclipse [quick fix](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_Quick_Fix%3F) function is useful.

Comment: @yukihane, I did as you said but it did not work. It shows with red underline which means it could get imported. I am sure I have used the required dependencies. I used Ctrl space to automatically be imported but it does not work either

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
I fixed it by adding the newer version.